# C++ initialization lists multiple initializations

Tags: c++, initialization-list

#### C++

```
#include <stdio.h>

class a
{ 
    public: 
        int var1; 
        a(int var) 
        {
            var1 = var; 
            printf("set var1 to %d\n", var1);
        } 
}; 
class b: public a 
{ 
    public: 
        int var2; 
        b(int d) : var2(d++), a(var2++)
        {
            printf("d: %d, var2: %d, var1: %d\n", d, var2, var1);
        } 
}; 

int main()
{ 
    int a = 5;
    b obj1(a);  
    printf("%d\n", obj1.var1);
}
```

Output:

```
set var1 to 0
d: 6, var2: 5, var1: 0
0
[Finished in 0.7s]
```

Why is `a.var1` not set to 6 here?

Comment: Using `a` as an int variable when you also have a public class named `a` obscures the code a bit, although isn't the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because C++ ignores the order in which you list the member initializations.  The base-class ctor is always called before other members are initialized.<sup>*</sup>

So I believe you're invoking **undefined behaviour** here; you're passing `var2` as the ctor argument, but it's not yet initialized.

---

<sub>* The compiler should warn you about this, if you allow it.  For example, compiling your code with GCC with the `-Wall` flag gives the following message:</sub>

```
test.cc: In constructor "b::b(int)":
test.cc:16: error: "b::var2" will be initialized after
test.cc:17: error:   base "a"
test.cc:17: error:   when initialized here
```